# wireshark in promiscous mode and firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, wireshark

My question is related to this one : [Wireshark does not capture Packets dropped by Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/620970/wireshark-does-not-capture-packets-dropped-by-firewall)
but that thread doesn't answer my query.

Say I have wireshark running in promiscous mode and my ethernet device as well the host driver all supoort promiscous mode. So my question is will the traffic that is set to be blocked in my firewall show up in the wireshark capture.

Comment: If your wireshark instance is setup mitm style, then yes.